# How to select n-first children until a specific class?

Tags: html, css

Considerate this HTML :

```
<div class="parent">
    <a id="1"></a>
    <a id="2"></a>
    <a id="3"></a>
    <a id="4"></a>
    <a id="5" class="specific"></a>
    <a id="6"></a>
    <a id="7"></a>
</div>
```

How can I select all the `<a>` tags untill -in this case- the fifth one ?

I tried this :

```
.parent a:not(.specific):first-of-type + a {
        color: red;
}
```

But only got the two first

Comment: This as far as I know is not possible, without knowing it's the 5th child.  There's no "until this selector" selector.  The answer below works, but is a sort of hack as it requires to to address _all_ items with the styles you want, then to override the _other_ items with the general sibling selector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't an "until" selector but you can always get what you want by doing the below.

Items from `.specific` on are red and the rest are green. Style them as you like but you can see how 1-5 are different from 5 on

```css
a {
  background: green;
}
a.specific,
a.specific ~ a {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <a id="1">qwe</a>
    <a id="2">wqe</a>
    <a id="3">wqe</a>
    <a id="4">wqe</a>
    <a id="5" class="specific">qwe</a>
    <a id="6">qwe</a>
    <a id="7">qwe</a>
</div>
```

Documentation is here for general sibling combinator https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors

> The general sibling combinator (~) separates two selectors and matches
>   the second element only if it follows the first element (though not
>   necessarily immediately), and both are children of the same parent
>   element.

If you want the 5th one to be green then use `a.specific ~ a` only if you don't want the 5th to be green the use what's in the snippet

Comment: This is a nice hack.  Too bad there's not a selector that does what OP asks ;)

Comment: Nice ! Didn't get what `~` could actually do ! ;) Accepted answer in 10min :)

Comment: Yea for a lot of things in css there is a workaround